How to update local variables in a DynamicModule?
I have a rather long computation, and I'd like to store it in a local variable, so I can operate on it, in multiple different ways for a small GUI in Mathematica.
Here's an example that demonstrates the problem:
  DynamicModule[{input1 = 0, input2 = 0, result},
       Dynamic[result = Sum[Prime[i], {i, 1, input1 + input2}]];
    
       Grid[{
          {"Input 1", InputField[Dynamic[input1], Number], Dynamic[input1]},
          {"Input 2", InputField[Dynamic[input2], Number], Dynamic[input2]},
          {"Result", Dynamic[result], Dynamic[N[Sqrt[result]]]}
       }]
    ]
  ]

When I run this code, result does not get updated when input1 and input2 get updated.  What am I doing wrong?
I'm running Mathematica 14.0.

Your module has this line
Dynamic[result = Sum[Prime[i], {i, 1, input1 + input2}]];

The semicolon is a problem because it means this Dynamic expression is never displayed, so the input never gets evaluated. Anything wrapped in Dynamic will only evaluate when displayed:

To fix your issue, just replace the Dynamic[result] in the grid with Dynamic[result = ....].  Since this is displayed, it will be evaluated and give result a value.
